# In Caverns of Thracia, where does this trap door lead to?

Tags: published-adventures, battle-map, odnd

In the original Caverns of Thracia, there is a trap door marked on the map.

> It is next to the statue in room 20, where the tribesmen prepare for their sacrifices.

Where does this lead to?

> Do the tribesmen know about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading through the module in some detail, I've found it.

> In room 40I, there is a 5' wide opening in the ceiling that leads up to room 20. This allows escape from the Wily Water Trap if you're good at climbing.

Answer (score 2):

According to the text of the module, it doesn't specify where it leads. (See Description of the Purification Hall).

However, if you want to extrapolate it, you can judge about where it would lead by comparing level 1 and level 2. The trap door (24) has a description that it leads to the pool below the rapids, and while they don't exactly line up, you could fudge that the trap door in the Hall drops them actually into the rapids.

[image: Room text descriptions]

[image]